# Как передать данные из label которая находится в mainwindow в label диалогового окна?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

В mainwindow находится кнопка и label, по нажатию на кнопку должно появится диалоговое окно, в котором находится кнопка и label, в label диалогового окна по нажатию на кнопку в диалоговом окне должно отобразится то что было в mainwindow в label.

//mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog |
                   Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint |
                   Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_click_clicked()
{
    shop window;
    window.setModal(true);
    window.exec();
}
```

//dialog.cpp

```
#include "shop.h"
#include "ui_shop.h"

double test(Ui::MainWindow * ui);

shop::shop(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::shop)
{
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window |
                         Qt::CustomizeWindowHint |
                         Qt::WindowTitleHint);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

shop::~shop()
{
    delete ui;
}

void shop::on_bu1_clicked()
{

}
```

Comment: Перед созданием диалогом (`exec()`) вставьте label'у диалога текст из label'а главного виджета

Comment: @gil9red а можете написать код, а то я не до конца понимаю что и куда вставлять

Comment: Хорошо, добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ваш код MaInWindow и Dialog :)

Comment: @gil9red добавил, по нажатию на кнопку bu1 из mainwindow нужно передать данные которые находятся в label, в label который находится в dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что у `shop` на форме есть `label` с названием (object name) `label_info`, а у `MainWindow` есть виджет `label_about`.

И обоих классов `ui` публичны. Если не публичны, то у `shop` сделайте публичный метод, что примет строку и установит ее в `label_info`.

Тогда, перед созданием диалога обратимся к одному `label` и возьмем текст, чтобы установить другому:

```
shop window;
window.setModal(true);
window.ui->label_info->setText(this->ui->label_about->text())
window.exec();
```

Comment: А как у shop сделать публичный метод?

Comment: Это основы с/c++... В файле h объявляете метод как публичный `public: void setText(const QString& text);`, в cpp файле метод реализуйте `void shop::setText(const QString& text) { ui->label_info->setText(text) }`, тогда в `MainWindow` будет `window->setText(this->ui->label_about->text())`

Comment: всё здорово, только вот нужно сделать по нажатию на кнопку в dialog

Comment: @TheHavlok, передайте тогда в `shop` или сам указатель на `label_about`, или указатель на `MainWindow` и сохраните его в `shop` (создайте в shop поле соответствующего типа). И при клике на кнопку в диалоге, обратитесь к тому новому полю и получите из него нужную инфу

Comment: спасибо, я же так сделал

Comment: @TheHavlok, вы молодец :)